# Why does this CollectionViewSource not sort on the enum's ToString() result?

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, collectionviewsource

I have a view model that is used to produce items for an `ItemsControl`:

```
public class PermissionItemViewModel
{
    public PermissionsEnum Permission {get; set;}
}
```

The enum itself is defined in a way that the list is not naturally in alphabetical order, and when the control renders, the items are in the same order as the enum definition.

In my view, I am trying to define a `CollectionViewSource` and make it sort those items by what would essentially be `myEnumValue.ToString()`.  Instead, the sort seems to be in order of the enum values instead of (what I thought would be) an implicit `ToString()` result.

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="permissionsViewSource"
                      Source="{Binding PermissionItems}">  <!-- ObservableCollection<PermissionItemViewModel> -->
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <cm:SortDescription PropertyName="Permission" />
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

Ultimately, I use the source like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource permissionsViewSource}}" />
```

I would like it to sort by the names of the enums, not their values.  How can I force it to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [you may be able to grab the `ListCollectionView` and do a custom sort on that.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24149695/424129)

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CollectionViewSource source = (CollectionViewSource)(this.Resources["MyCollectionViewSource1"]);
    ListCollectionView view = (ListCollectionView)source.View;
    view.CustomSort = new CustomSorter();
}

public class CustomSorter : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        var itemx = x as PermissionItemViewModel;
        var itemy = y as PermissionItemViewModel;

        return $"{itemx.Permission}".CompareTo($"{itemy.Permission}");
    }
}
```

You could salve your conscience a bit by writing this as an attached behavior for `CollectionViewSource` that would take a property name for its value. Offhand I think you'd want that to set up a property changed handler on `View` -- I think I wrote such a thing once, let's see if I can exhume it...

Comment: If you have an example, it would help.  I tried the behavior thing myself, but I never get a valid `View`.  All the events in the behavior seem to fire before it's established, so I've nothing to assign a sorter to.

Comment: Scratch that.  There's a `Filter` event on the `CollectionViewSource` that I can use.  I just put a condition in there to only set the sorter once and it seems to work fine.  Thanks, Ed.