# WPF ICollectionView Group Order and Defaults

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, icollectionview

I have a collection of items that I am displaying in a DataGrid in WPF.

These items have the property `Status`, which can either be `Approved`, `Pending`, `Draft` or `Archived`.

I have set up an `ICollectionView` as follows:

```
formView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Forms);
PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("Status");
formView.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);
```

I then bind this view to the DataGrid and it correctly groups and display my items.

My issue, is I need Archived to be at the bottom of the list, and collapsed by default however my binding automatically puts it before the other status. How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either sort the source collection:

```
var formView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Forms.OrderBy(x =>
{
    switch (x.Status)
    {
        case "Archived":
            return 1;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}));
```

Or the `CollectionView`:

[CollectionViewSource with custom sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24147585/collectionviewsource-with-custom-sort)

Comment: Perfect. Slightly modified your code to fit my project and it worked perfectly. Thanks!